# How to deal with optional GET argument?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have a GET request that sometimes has `pk` argument and sometimes hasn't.
I want to have 1 view that deals with it, but my attempts to write it are not successful. Here is what I have:

```
@ajax
@login_required
def search_dist(request):
    try:
        pk = request.GET.get('pk')
    except Exception:
        dist_list = request.user.distributors.all()
        starts_with = request.GET.get('query')
        if starts_with:
            dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(
                surname__istartswith=starts_with)
        return render(request, 'distributors/distributors_list.html', {'distributors': dist_list})
    else:
        dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(
            distributors_of_links=get_object_or_404(Link, pk=pk))
        starts_with = request.GET.get('query')
        if starts_with:
            dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(distributors_of_links=get_object_or_404(
                Link, pk=pk)).filter(surname__istartswith=starts_with)
        return render(request, 'distributors/distributors_list.html', {'distributors': dist_list})
```

Part of my models:

```
class Distributor(models.Model):


class Link(models.Model):
    distributors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Distributor, blank=True, related_name='distributors_of_links')


class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    distributors = models.ManyToManyField(
        Distributor, blank=True, related_name='distributors_of_user')
```

with query: `search_dist?query=V` I have:

```
GET /distributors/search_dist   404 NOT FOUND
No Link matches the given query.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `pk = request.GET.get('pk')` won't raise an exception. It gives you None instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pk = request.GET.get('pk')
```

does not raise an exception. It gives you `None` instead, if pk isn't in GET.
So your first case never executes.
Try with:

```
@ajax
@login_required
def search_dist(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
    if pk is None:
        dist_list = request.user.distributors.all()
        starts_with = request.GET.get('query')
        if starts_with:
            dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(
                surname__istartswith=starts_with)
        return render(request, 'distributors/distributors_list.html', {'distributors': dist_list})
    else:
        dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(
            distributors_of_links=get_object_or_404(Link, pk=pk))
        starts_with = request.GET.get('query')
        if starts_with:
            dist_list = request.user.distributors.filter(distributors_of_links=get_object_or_404(
                Link, pk=pk)).filter(surname__istartswith=starts_with)
        return render(request, 'distributors/distributors_list.html', {'distributors': dist_list})
```

Comment: This has worked, thanks. What doest `,  None` in `pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)` mean?

Comment: `get()` take an optional second argument which is the value to return if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. The default value is `None`, here you are explicitly returning `None`.

Comment: exactly, I added None to make things more explicit. It is not required if you want None in case the key is absent.